# ACS: search.in doesn't support special characters in odata filters syntax

Tags: filter, odata, azure-cognitive-search, acs, azure-search-.net-sdk

Special characters are not working with search.in operator in ACS for example this doesn't fetch any value from ACS
`search.in(category, 'Books & reference')`.
I have also tried to encode the special characters as follows but still no luck.

```
search.in(category, 'Books%20%26%20reference')
search.in(category, 'Books %26 reference')
search.in(category, 'Books+%26+reference')
search.in(category, 'Books &amp; reference')
```

The only way it works is using the `eq` operator as follows

```
category eq 'Books & reference'
```

but as per ACS documentation seach.in is more performant and also convenient when there are multiple values of the attribute to filter for example

```
search.in(category, 'Movies,Education,Tools')
```

is more convenient than using eq operator as follows

```
category eq 'Books' OR category eq 'Education' OR category eq 'Tools'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by changing:

```
search.in(category, 'Books & reference')
```

to

```
search.in(category, 'Books & reference', '|')
```

Essentially in the first, `space` is being treated as a delimiter. In the second, you are explicitly telling to use a `pipe (|)` as a delimiter.

Considering pipe character is no where in your search values, your category field is searched for `Books & reference` whereas in the first case, the search is performed for `Book`, `&`, and `reference` values in category field.

This is what the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-search-in-function#syntax) say about the delimiters (**emphasis** mine):

> A string where each character is treated as a separator when parsing
> the valueList parameter. The default value of this parameter is ' ,'
> **which means that any values with spaces and/or commas between them
> will be separated**. If you need to use separators other than spaces and
> commas because your values include those characters, you can specify
> alternate delimiters such as '|' in this parameter.